# Survival Curves with pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to plot Kaplan-Meier (survival) curves with pgfplots from output generated in Mathematica.

A typical output table would look something like this:

211 1

253 1

307 1

344 0

365 0

365 1

383 0

383 1

391 0
...

the first column contains event dates; the second is the censoring data.

Is there a package, or built-in way of plotting the resulting survival curve, including censoring marks?

Comment: Does this question help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226712/32374

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possible to do in PGFPlots using a couple of column definition.

Let's assume you have the following data table (taken from the [example on the German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan-Meier-Sch%C3%A4tzer)) in a file called `data.txt`:

```
Days Event
10 0
12 1
22 0
29 1
31 1
36 0
38 0
50 0
60 0
61 1
70 1
88 0
99 0
110 0
140 0
```

You can read the data using

```
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\rawdata
```

Then you can add a dummy data row to make sure the plot begins at `t=0`:

```
\pgfplotstableread{
Days Event
0 1
}\datatable

\pgfplotstablevertcat{\datatable}{\rawdata}
```

Using this, you can calculate the number of survivors minus the censored cases, and the survival rate using:

```
\def\initialn{15} % Initial number of cases
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr accum={\pgfmathaccuma-1}{\initialn+2}]{n}{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr accum={\pgfmathaccuma*(\thisrow{n}-\thisrow{Event})/(\thisrow{n})}{(\initialn+1)/\initialn}]{s}{\datatable}
```

This can then be plotted like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, ymin=0]
\addplot [no markers, const plot, red] table [y=s] {\datatable};
\addplot [only marks, mark=+] table [y expr={(\thisrow{Event}==0 ? \thisrow{s} : inf )}] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

---

Complete example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable, filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
Days Event
10 0
12 1
22 0
29 1
31 1
36 0
38 0
50 0
60 0
61 1
70 1
88 0
99 0
110 0
140 0
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{data.txt}\rawdata

\pgfplotstableread{
Days Event
0 1
}\datatable

\pgfplotstablevertcat{\datatable}{\rawdata}

\def\initialn{15}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr accum={\pgfmathaccuma-1}{\initialn+2}]{n}{\datatable}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[expr accum={\pgfmathaccuma*(\thisrow{n}-\thisrow{Event})/(\thisrow{n})}{(\initialn+1)/\initialn}]{s}{\datatable}

\pgfplotstabletypeset{\datatable}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin=0, ymin=0]
\addplot [no markers, const plot, red] table [y=s] {\datatable};
\addplot [only marks, mark=+] table [y expr={(\thisrow{Event}==0 ? \thisrow{s} : inf )}] {\datatable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```